# How to get the twitter, facebook shared id in SLComposeViewController ios?

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter

I have developed the social(Facebook, Twitter) sharing via SLComposeViewController in Social framwork. It is possible to get the facebook, twitter shared id of post in SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler?

If it possible suggest me some example.

Example Code

```
     SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    tweetSheet.completionHandler = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){

        NSLog(@"here how to get the post shared id?");
    } ;

    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Sharing from my own app! :)"];
    [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        tweetSheet.completionHandler = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
            NSLog(@"");
        } ;
In Completion handler method it will only return the result code. But i need the facebook, twitter post shared id. Its possible via Social Framework in ios?

Comment: Please add you code to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to get the Facebook, twitter post share id via SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler.

Instead I used the SLRequest to share post on twitter and facebook and to get the shared id for the post.

Example code

```
NSLog(@"share on Facebook");
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"];

SLRequest *facebookRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                                requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                          URL:url
                                                   parameters:postparameter];

facebookRequest.account = facebookAccount;//Facebook Account Object

[facebookRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
    NSDictionary *postResponseData = nil;
    NSString *fbShareId = nil;
    if (responseData) {

        NSInteger statusCode = urlResponse.statusCode;
        if (statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 300) {
            postResponseData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                               options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                 error:NULL];
            fbShareId = postResponseData[@"id"];
            NSLog(@"[SUCCESS!] Created post in facebook with ID: %@", fbShareId);

        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"[ERROR] Server responded: status code %d %@", statusCode,

                  [NSHTTPURLResponse localizedStringForStatusCode:statusCode]);

        }
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"[ERROR] An error occurred while posting: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

    }

}];
```